# Asterisk:undefined reference to `SQLAllocHandle'

Tags: c, asterisk

I added a test.c in `asterisk/main` directory to test ODBC. Unfortunately it shows like below when I run `make`.

```
test.o: In function `test_function':
/usr/src/asterisk-certified-13.8-cert3/main/libtest.c:10: 
undefined     reference to `SQLAllocHandle'
```

`test.c` like this:

```
#include "asterisk/res_odbc.h"

ASTERISK_FILE_VERSION(__FILE__, "$Revision$")


int test_function(void){
    int res;
    SQLHANDLE output_handle;
    res = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV,  SQL_NULL_HANDLE,   &output_handle);

    if ( (res != SQL_SUCCESS) && (res != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) ) {
        ast_log(LOG_DEBUG, "AllocHandle Success!\n");
        } else {
            ast_log(LOG_WARNING, "Error AllocHandle");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Note: `res_odbc` included `<sql.h>`,`<sqlext.h>` and `<sqltypes.h>`

Comment: It is a linker error, so the code snippet and the .h files are not relevant at all.  You forgot to link the odbc library.

Comment: How to link odbc library? I thought just need to include the header file.

Answer (score 0):

You should change Makefile for include libs into your module.

But that is WRONG method when you working with asterisk.

Correct method is user REALTIME or func_odbc and make it care about connection.

Comment: what does  REALTIME and func_odbc mean?

Comment: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Realtime+Database+Configuration